# Permanent MapNetworkDrive

Tags: vbscript

Basically, I got a VBScript that gathers the username from the currently logged in user, and then map its `\\MYSERVER\Users\<username>` to a driveletter (`J:`). What I'm having trouble with is making this permanent, staying there after reboot/logout. This is the code I'm using:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objNetwork 
Dim strDriveLetter, strRemotePath, strUserName
strDriveLetter = "J:" 
strRemotePath = "\\MYSERVER\Users" 

Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
strUserName = objNetwork.UserName 
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath _
  & "\" & strUserName

WScript.Echo " Launch Explorer, check: "& strDriveLetter
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> ### Syntax
>
> `object.MapNetworkDrive(strLocalName, strRemoteName, [bUpdateProfile], [strUser], [strPassword])`
>
> ### Arguments
>
> [...]
>   *bUpdateProfile*
>   Optional. Boolean value indicating whether the mapping information is stored in the current user's profile. If *bUpdateProfile* is supplied and has a value of **true**, the mapping is stored in the user profile (the default is **false**).

So you need to change this:

```
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath _
  & "\" & strUserName
```

into this:

```
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath _
  & "\" & strUserName, True
```

Answer (score 1):

[MapNetworkDrive Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6(v=vs.84).aspx): Adds a shared network drive to your computer system.

```
object.MapNetworkDrive(sLocalName, sRemoteName, [bUpdateProfile], [sUser], [sPassword])
```

> Arguments
>
> - `object` WshNetwork object.
> - `sLocalName` String value indicating the name by which the mapped drive will be known locally.
> - `sRemoteName` String value indicating the share's UNC name (`\\xxx\yyy`).
> - `bUpdateProfile` Optional. Boolean value indicating whether the mapping information is stored in the current user's profile. If
>     bUpdateProfile is supplied and has a value of `true`, the mapping is
>     stored in the user profile (the default is `false`).
> - `sUser` Optional. String value indicating the user name. You must supply this argument if you are mapping a network drive using the
>     credentials of someone other than the current user.
> - `sPassword` Optional. String value indicating the user password. You must supply this argument if you are mapping a network drive using the
>     credentials of someone other than the current user.

However, using

```
 objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath & "\" & strUserName, True
```

could raise some errors, for instance

- `-2147024811` The local device name is already in use (`&H80070055`), or
- `-2147023694` The local device name has a remembered connection to another network resource (`&H800704B2`).

Note that next code snippet to check mapped drives and conditionally remove current drive mapping merely if it exists could fail

```
On Error GoTo 0
Dim oDrives, i
Set oDrives = objNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
For i = 0 to oDrives.Count - 1 Step 2
  If oDrives.Item( i) = strDriveLetter Then
    ' remove current drive mapping, force the removal, force persistent
    objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, True, True
    ' and wait for network drive removal (this could take some time)
    Wscript.Sleep 800
    Exit For
  End If  
Next
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath & "\" & strUserName, True
```

if there is *pending* (still *remembered* but not enumerated with `EnumNetworkDrives`) drive mapping disconnected temporarily, e.g. by `objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, True, False`

Hence, involve some *basic error handling* as follows:

```
On Error Resume Next
  ' remove current drive mapping, force the removal, force persistent
  objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, True, True
  ' and wait for network drive removal (this could take some time) 
  Wscript.Sleep 800
  Err.Clear
  ' map network drive, force persistent
  objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath & "\" & strUserName, True
On Error GoTo 0
```